# How to load into ImageView if I have string which contains image position on /mnt/sdcard...?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to load into ImageView if I have string which contains image position on /mnt/sdcard... ?
I know to create Bitmap from uri with InputStream, but how to solve this when I have String path parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
ImageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg").toString()));
```

or

```
ImageView.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg")));
```

If it includes /mnt just check for :

```
if(test.contains("/mount")){
test.replace("/mount","");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
mImageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File("/sdcard/photo.jpg").toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try this,
 Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(yourpath);
            BitmapDrawable imageDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(imageBitmap);

yourImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imageDrawable);
```

Comment: String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/"+yourString;

Answer (score 1):

You can use setImageURI() method of ImageView to set image from any path

```
imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("/sdcard/images5.jpg"));
```